# Edição de gráfico no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como devo proceder para substituir o texto da legenda no gráfico abaixo de "mean.est" e "mean.obs" para "est" e "obs"?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo reprodutivo:

```
ano<-c("2009", "2011", "2013","2014","2016","2017","2018","2019")
mean.est<-c(0.975, 1.204, 1.504, 1.741, 1.77,2.166,2.378,2.564)
lower<-c(0.041, 0.771, 1.114, 1.374, 1.419,1.804,1.993, 2.12)
upper<-c(1.876, 1.669, 1.867, 2.081, 2.162, 2.499,2.745, 3.021)
mean.obs<-c(2.659, 1.155, 1.56, 1.848, 1.56,2.253,2.407,2.541)
graf<-data.frame(ano,mean.est, lower, upper, mean.obs)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Anos <- seq(min(as.integer(graf$ano)), max(as.integer(graf$ano)), by = 2)

graf %>%
  mutate(ano = as.integer(ano)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('mean'),
    names_to = 'group',
    values_to = 'mean'
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ano, y = mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(mean.est = 'blue', mean.obs = 'black')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = Anos, labels = Anos) +
  ylab("Número de abates (log)") +
  xlab("Ano") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.1),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white")
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como [respondido por Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/490433/117168), se os novos termos ("est" e "obs") serão usados continuamente no seu fluxo de trabalho, o mais prático é alterá-los diretamente no conjunto de dados.

Em casos onde isso não é possível ou desejável, pode-se usar a opção `labels` para indicar rótulos personalizados:

```
scale_color_manual(values = c(mean.est = "blue", mean.obs = "black"),
                   labels = c(mean.est = "est", mean.obs = "obs"))
```

Como sempre no R, se eles forem usados diversas vezes, pode armazená-los em um objeto. Por exemplo:

```
cores <- c(est = "lightblue", obs = "gray", mean.est = "blue", mean.obs = "black")
rotulos <- c(est = "estimado", obs = "observado", mean.est = "est", mean.obs = "obs")

...
scale_color_manual(values = cores, labels = rotulos)
```

Confira `?ggplot2::as_labeller` se quiser criar rotuladores mais elaborados.

Answer (score 4):

Altere os nomes `mean.est` e `mean.obs` no próprio conjunto de dados. Isso vai evitar muitas manipulações desnecessárias com o `ggplot2`. Uma forma que sugiro para fazer isso é através da função `ifelse`. A linha

```
mutate(group = ifelse(group == "mean.est", "est", "obs"))
```

que coloquei imediatamente antes da chamada do `ggplot` abaixo compara quais valores de `group` são iguais a `mean.est`. Os que forem iguais ele substitui por `est` e, os que não forem, ele substitui por `obs`.

Também fiz alterações pontuais nos argumentos da função `scale_color_manual` para refletir as alterações nos valores da variável `group`.

```r
graf %>%
  mutate(ano = as.integer(ano)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('mean'),
    names_to = 'group',
    values_to = 'mean'
  ) %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(group == "mean.est", "est", "obs")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ano, y = mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(est = 'blue', obs = 'black')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = Anos, labels = Anos) +
  ylab("Número de abates (log)") +
  xlab("Ano") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.1),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>